# Firebase Created Dynamic links from PHP API not showing in console

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created firebase dynamic links from our PHP API. Created link showing with the response, but not showing in firebase console dashboard.

Please check below response from API.

```
{
"result": {
"shortLink": "https://sample-xyz.page.link/UVJLgCH12gCMNdu66",
"warning": [
  {
    "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
    "warningMessage": "Android app 'com.sample-xyz.beta' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#android-sha256-absent]"
  },
  {
    "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
    "warningMessage": "We could not find Android package name 'test_bundle_v_1.0.54' in your Google project. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#app-not-in-project]"
  },
  {
    "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
    "warningMessage": "There is no configuration to prevent phishing on this domain https://sample-xyz.page.link. Setup URL patterns to whitelist in the Firebase Dynamic Links console. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429]"
  }
 ],
 "previewLink": "https://sample-xyz.page.link/UVJLgCH12gCMNdu66?d=1"
 }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, dynamic links created through the API won't show up in the console.
Only when going to `Events>dynamic_link_first_open`, `dynamic_link_app_open` or `dynamic_link_app_update` will you be able to view statistics coming into your app. Which is quite unfortunate.
But using the Google Analytics parameters when creating your dynamic link it should be possible to view some more/better statistics.